# Delphi REST GET but not POST works with AusPost eParcel API

Tags: rest, delphi

I'm working on an integration project for a client that requires creating AusPost shipments using the eParcel REST API from a Delphi 10.2 Tokyo service program.

Here is what I have as the `Constructor` for my class:

```pascal
constructor TAusPostRESTServices.Create;
begin
  // Create the REST objects

  HTTPBasicAuthenticator := THTTPBasicAuthenticator.Create(API_KEY, API_PASSWORD);
  RESTClient := TRESTClient.Create(BASE_URL);
  RESTResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(nil);
  RESTRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);

  // Set the initial properties

  RESTClient.Params.Clear;
  RESTClient.HandleRedirects := true;
  RESTClient.Authenticator := HTTPBasicAuthenticator;
  RESTClient.RaiseExceptionOn500 := false;

  RESTRequest.Client := RESTClient;
  RESTRequest.Response := RESTResponse;
  RESTRequest.SynchronizedEvents := false;
end;
```

And the constants it uses (note that the account and API values are from the reference API and probably don't actually work).

```pascal
const
  BASE_URL = 'https://digitalapi.auspost.com.au/test';
  ACCOUNT = '0000123456';
  API_KEY = '601a4032-6dbd-46aa-9c6c-8c6dacca5e61';
  API_PASSWORD = 'password';
```

The `Uses` clause has at least these:

```pascal
REST.Client, REST.Authenticator.Basic, IPPeerClient, JSON, REST.Types
```

The eParcel API methods I'm trying to use are [Create Shipments](https://developers.auspost.com.au/apis/shipping-and-tracking/reference/create-shipments) and [Get Shipments](https://developers.auspost.com.au/apis/shipping-and-tracking/reference/get-shipments).

Here is what my Get Shipments Delphi code looks like (Don't worry about the `AJSONValue` response. Still working on what that will do eventually):

```pascal
function TAusPostRESTServices.GetShipments(var AError: String): Boolean;
var
  AStatusCode: Integer;
  AJSONString: String;
  AJSONValue: TJSonValue;
  AParameter: TRESTRequestParameter;
begin
  // Set the request header info

  RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;
  RESTRequest.Resource := '/shipping/v1/shipments';
  RESTRequest.Accept := 'application/json';

  AParameter := RESTRequest.Params.AddItem;
  AParameter.ContentType := ctAPPLICATION_JSON;
  AParameter.name := 'Content-Type';
  AParameter.Value := 'application/json';
  AParameter.Kind := TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER;

  RESTRequest.Params.AddHeader('account-number', ACCOUNT);

  try
    try
      RESTRequest.Execute;
    except on E: Exception do
      ;
    end;

    // If the StatusCode is 200, then the REST method worked

    AStatusCode := RESTRequest.Response.StatusCode;

    if AStatusCode <> 200 then
      AError := RESTRequest.Response.Content
    else
    begin
      AJSONValue := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(RESTRequest.Response.Content);

      AJSONValue.Free;

      AError := '';
    end;
  finally
    Result := (AError = '');
  end;
end;
```

This works fine and returns the one trial demo shipment I created using Postman, from the sample JSON included in the AusPost API documentation.

```json
{
  "shipments": [
    {
      "shipment_id": "T7sK0EA9HGcAAAFufLYgUxkK",
      "shipment_reference": "My second shipment ref",
      "shipment_creation_date": "2019-10-30T06:42:42+11:00",
      "customer_reference_1": "cb1234",
      "customer_reference_2": "cb2345",
      "sender_references": [
        "cb1234",
        "cb2345"
      ],
      "from": {
        "type": "MERCHANT_LOCATION",
        "lines": [
          "111 Bourke St"
        ],
        "suburb": "Melbourne",
        "postcode": "3000",
        "state": "VIC",
        "apcn": "2468013579",
        "name": "Carl Block",
        "country": "AU"
      },
      "to": {
        "type": "STANDARD_ADDRESS",
        "lines": [
          "PO Box 123"
        ],
        "suburb": "Rye",
        "postcode": "3941",
        "state": "VIC",
        "apcn": "1234567890",
        "name": "Blocked Carl",
        "business_name": "In debt",
        "country": "AU",
        "email": "carl@gmai.co",
        "phone": "0356567567",
        "delivery_instructions": "please leave behind shed"
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "weight": 1,
          "height": 10,
          "length": 10,
          "width": 10,
          "contains_dangerous_goods": false,
          "authority_to_leave": true,
          "safe_drop_enabled": true,
          "allow_partial_delivery": false,
          "item_id": "3mQK0EA9CksAAAFui7YgUxkK",
          "item_reference": "blocked",
          "tracking_details": {
            "article_id": "111JD538925401000930800",
            "consignment_id": "111JD5389254"
          },
          "product_id": "7E55",
          "item_summary": {
            "total_cost": 11.48,
            "total_cost_ex_gst": 11.48,
            "total_gst": 0,
            "status": "Created"
          },
          "item_contents": [],
          "label": {
            "status": "Pending",
            "errors": []
          },
          "postage_details": {
            "price": {
              "calculated_price": 11.48,
              "calculated_price_ex_gst": 11.48,
              "calculated_gst": 0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "weight": 2.123,
          "height": 10,
          "length": 100.1,
          "width": 10,
          "contains_dangerous_goods": false,
          "authority_to_leave": true,
          "safe_drop_enabled": true,
          "allow_partial_delivery": false,
          "item_id": "9cgK0EA9smIAAAFufrYgUxkK",
          "item_reference": "blocked",
          "tracking_details": {
            "article_id": "111JD538925403000930804",
            "consignment_id": "111JD5389254"
          },
          "product_id": "7E55",
          "item_summary": {
            "total_cost": 23.34,
            "total_cost_ex_gst": 23.34,
            "total_gst": 0,
            "status": "Created"
          },
          "item_contents": [],
          "label": {
            "status": "Pending",
            "errors": []
          },
          "postage_details": {
            "price": {
              "calculated_price": 23.34,
              "calculated_price_ex_gst": 23.34,
              "calculated_gst": 0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "weight": 1,
          "height": 10,
          "length": 10,
          "width": 10,
          "contains_dangerous_goods": false,
          "authority_to_leave": true,
          "safe_drop_enabled": true,
          "allow_partial_delivery": false,
          "item_id": "_hEK0EA9zIIAAAFuirYgUxkK",
          "item_reference": "blocked",
          "tracking_details": {
            "article_id": "111JD538925402000930807",
            "consignment_id": "111JD5389254"
          },
          "product_id": "7E55",
          "item_summary": {
            "total_cost": 11.48,
            "total_cost_ex_gst": 11.48,
            "total_gst": 0,
            "status": "Created"
          },
          "item_contents": [],
          "label": {
            "status": "Pending",
            "errors": []
          },
          "postage_details": {
            "price": {
              "calculated_price": 11.48,
              "calculated_price_ex_gst": 11.48,
              "calculated_gst": 0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "options": {},
      "shipment_summary": {
        "total_cost": 47.41,
        "total_cost_ex_gst": 43.1,
        "fuel_surcharge": 1.11,
        "total_gst": 4.31,
        "status": "Created",
        "tracking_summary": {
          "Created": 3
        },
        "number_of_items": 3
      },
      "movement_type": "DESPATCH",
      "charge_to_account": "1001746337"
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "total_number_of_records": 1,
    "number_of_records_per_page": 1000,
    "current_page_number": 1
  }
}
```

My Create Shipment is almost identical:

```pascal
function TAusPostRESTServices.CreateShipment(var AError: String): Boolean;
var
  AStatusCode: Integer;
  AJSONString: String;
  AJSONValue: TJSonValue;
  AParameter: TRESTRequestParameter;
begin
  // Set the request header info

  RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
  RESTRequest.Resource := '/shipping/v1/shipments';
  RESTRequest.Accept := 'application/json';

  AParameter := RESTRequest.Params.AddItem;
  AParameter.ContentType := ctAPPLICATION_JSON;
  AParameter.name := 'Content-Type';
  AParameter.Value := 'application/json';
  AParameter.Kind := TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER;

  RESTRequest.Params.AddHeader('account-number', ACCOUNT);

  try
    AJSONString := '{'+
                   '  "shipments": ['+
                   '    {'+
                   '      "shipment_reference": "139301",'+
                   '      "customer_reference_1": "1",'+
                   '      "from": {'+
                   '        "name": "MERCHANT_LOCATION",'+
                   '        "lines": ['+
                   '          "111 Bourke St"'+
                   '        ],'+
                   '        "suburb": "MELBOURNE",'+
                   '        "postcode": "3000",'+
                   '        "state": "VIC"'+
                   '      },'+
                   '      "to": {'+
                   '        "name": "STANDARD_ADDRESS",'+
                   '        "lines": ['+
                   '          "PO Box 123"'+
                   '        ],'+
                   '        "suburb": "Rye",'+
                   '        "state": "VIC",'+
                   '        "postcode": "3941",'+
                   '        "delivery_instructions": "please leave behind shed",'+
                   '        "email": "carl@gmai.co"'+
                   '      },'+
                   '      "items": ['+
                   '        {'+
                   '          "width": 10,'+
                   '          "height": 10,'+
                   '          "length": 10,'+
                   '          "weight": 0.19,'+
                   '          "product_id": "7E55",'+
                   '          "authority_to_leave": true'+
                   '        }'+
                   '      ]'+
                   '    }'+
                   '  ]'+
                   '}';

    RESTRequest.Body.Add(AJSONString, ctAPPLICATION_JSON);

    try
      RESTRequest.Execute;
    except on E: Exception do
      ;
    end;

    // If the StatusCode is 200, then the REST method worked

    AStatusCode := RESTRequest.Response.StatusCode;

    if AStatusCode <> 200 then
      AError := RESTRequest.Response.Content
    else
    begin
      AJSONValue := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(RESTRequest.Response.Content);

      AJSONValue.Free;

      AError := '';
    end;
  finally
    Result := (AError = '');
  end;
end;
```

When this is run, the status code is 404 and the content text is

```json
{
  "code": "404",
  "name": "Not Found",
  "message": "Invalid HTTP method POST or request path /shipments. Please refer to the Developer Centre reference at https://developers.auspost.com.au/apis/shipping-and-tracking/reference for correct usage."
}
```

But if I setup that Create Shipment POST in Postman, with the Raw Body being the same JSON string, it works fine, and I get an appropriate response:

```json
{
    "shipments": [
        {
            "shipment_id": "QdkK0EA99JoAAAFuba0gUzkF",
            "shipment_reference": "139301",
            "shipment_creation_date": "2019-11-05T11:45:03+11:00",
            "items": [
                {
                    "weight": 0.190,
                    "authority_to_leave": true,
                    "safe_drop_enabled": true,
                    "allow_partial_delivery": true,
                    "item_id": "kwgK0EA9Es8AAAFubq0gUzkF",
                    "tracking_details": {
                        "article_id": "111JD539319101000931501",
                        "consignment_id": "111JD5393191"
                    },
                    "product_id": "7E55",
                    "item_summary": {
                        "total_cost": 17.14,
                        "total_cost_ex_gst": 17.14,
                        "total_gst": 0.00,
                        "status": "Created"
                    },
                    "item_contents": []
                }
            ],
            "options": {},
            "shipment_summary": {
                "total_cost": 17.55,
                "total_cost_ex_gst": 15.95,
                "fuel_surcharge": 0.41,
                "total_gst": 1.60,
                "status": "Created",
                "tracking_summary": {
                    "Created": 1
                },
                "number_of_items": 1
            },
            "movement_type": "DESPATCH",
            "charge_to_account": "1001746337"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I don't understand is why Delphi is giving me this 404 error. If I don't include the body in the request when using Postman, it gives me this response:

```json
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "400",
            "name": "INVALID_PAYLOAD",
            "message": "Unable to deserialize payload.  Please ensure that the payload is valid JSON. Please note that when assigned, boolean fields can only accept 'true' or 'false' as values."
        }
    ]
}
```

But if I don't include the body in the request from Delphi, I get the same 404 error. Does anyone know of a different REST API that I can try my code with? Or has anyone successfully used the AusPost eParcel API from Delphi, even if it was done with Indy?

Comment: It'd be better if you provided your complete code for CreateShipment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, even if I can't explain it. Once I removed the Content-Type parameter code, the post method worked fine.

```
// AParameter := RESTRequest.Params.AddItem;
// AParameter.ContentType := ctAPPLICATION_JSON;
// AParameter.name := 'Content-Type';
// AParameter.Value := 'application/json';
// AParameter.Kind := TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER;
```

Somehow, including that in the request just stuffs things up. No explanation as to why, but it may just be one of those Delphi REST library quirks.